# Is there a possible way to add profile id configuration to microsoft as custom provider using NextAuth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

As I am configuring microsoft as custom provider I should signin and be redirected to dashboard
However signin is rasing missing profile Id issue in terminal

## Microsoft custom configuration

```
     id: "microsoft",
     name: "Microsoft",
     type: "oauth",
     wellKnown: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
     authorization: { params: { scope: "openid email profile offline_access User.Read" } },
     idToken: true,
     checks: ["pkce", "state"],
     clientId: process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID as string,
     clientSecret: process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
     profile(profile) {
      return {
         id: profile?.id,
         name: profile?.name,
         email: profile?.email,
         image: profile?.picture,
       }
     
     },
   },
```

## Console output

```
OAuthProfile: {
    ver: '2.0',
    iss: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0',
    sub: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEj0VHr66OeDVlOkGzlng_k',
    aud: 'e683f83b-7c7f-43b9-9459-3809383faecc',
    exp: 1685026583,
    iat: 1684939883,
    nbf: 1684939883,
    name: 'MY_REAL_NAME J',
    preferred_username: 'myrealemail@outlook.com',
    oid: '00000000-0000-0000-b109-73671a9a345e',
    email: 'myrealemail@outlook.com',
    tid: '9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad',
    aio: 'DYMxVASumeOlAxzvg7VgZ!t4lmBw2mitZPscW2QGYsPfv44x9i1nxvoD8eZHM53Q5I9EDygwIBTGyB0cgzob!3SpDT5U6XHpOOpfytrPAzVt9sQpKqJIAQWSlEp!CgRNrtpP95Qj!C*eJu3czpX041A$'
  },
  message: 'Profile id is missing in Microsoft OAuth profile response'
}
```

## Expected result

As a user I should be redirected to `http://localhost:3000/dashoard` instead of `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin`